# Angle of a cone from two different angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The situation is as follows. I have an aircraft (a point), and a ray coming down from this point straight towards the ground (A). It stops once it hits the ground. I have another ray (K) coming out of the bottom of the aircraft. It travels downwards relative to the aircraft, not straight down. The length of this ray is known, and greater than A.
The aircraft has two sensors which will tell me the angle of pitch and roll.
I am looking to take the K ray coming out of the bottom of the aircraft, and revolve it into a cone, and know the angle of this cone using the pitch and roll angles given to me by the sensors.

So I need to know figure out how to take two angles, and use them to revolve a ray coming out of the aircraft into a cone with a known angle.

EDIT:
I am trying to determine how far this aircraft is off being aligned with the horizon with just pitch and roll values being given.

If it helps the equation I have created to find the altitude from the angle in a TWO DIMENSIONAL space is:

$a = \sqrt(K^2 - (K-sin(\theta))^2$

Where "a" is the altitude, "K" is the distance sensor distance and theta is the angle of the aircraft from being aligned with the horizon

Sorry this isn't very clear, my first post here and I'm not fluent in all the math terminology which I'm sure would make this easier to follow. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Out of interest are you an aircraft engineer? Why do you  need to know this? A diagram might help.

Comment: No, I am not an aircraft engineer, yet, but it's where I plan to go. Working on flight controls for a model aircraft and I've gotten the math to work in one dimension. The goal is to obtain a rough estimate of aircraft altitude regardless of orientation without any actual altitude sensors (don't have any on hand)
TL;DR, I need to obtain rough altitude with only an ultrasonic or LIDAR distance sensor and a way to measure tilt.

Comment: I suppose I can re-word the question to say I just need to be able to use two angle measures 90 degrees apart to be able to tell how far the aircraft is from being perfectly aligned with the horizon

Comment: In other words: you want to know how to compute the angle between A and K, using the pitch and roll angles. Correct?

Comment: You have two rays - one goes directly down, no matter the state of the plan. The other ray is "attached" to the aircraft directly from the bottom of the aircraft. What is not clear - apart from pitch and roll what information is known?

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the point where I believe the only information I believe is relevant in this case is pitch and roll, but the distance given by the sensor on the bottom of the aircraft (Ray K) is also known.
What I am looking for is the absolute angle of the aircraft relative to the horizon. Like if I had a plate balancing on a pencil, I want to just know how many degrees away from being level that plate is, if the plates pitch and roll is given.

Comment: I will create some sort of image to help explain when I get the chance, sorry the question isn't super clear, I'm not sure how to explain it.

Comment: I've solved the issue at its source by using an IMU with telemetry to get altitude without fuss. Thanks for the help.